# 2D Positioning of mobile robot

Tags: mobile-robot, sensors, localization

I am just starting to explore an idea and I am somewhat of a novice in robotics. I am looking to position a mobile robot as accurately as possible on a concrete slab. This would be during new construction of a building and probably not have many walls or other vertical points for reference. the basic premise behind the robot is to print floor plans straight on to the slab. I will have access to the BIM (building information models, CAD, Revit) files of the building. I want the robot to position itself as accurately as possible on the blank slab using the BIM files as a map. What would be the best avenue to track and adjust positioning of the robot in the open space of a slab? Low frequency, Lidar, wifi? Lastly what sensors would be best?

Comment: I voted to close this question because it's an open-ended design question - the "best" technology and "best" sensor depends on your particular application. For instance, how would you use any rangefinders? (Lidar, sonar, etc.) You would need targets established somewhere to locate the robot, and you would need those targets to be accurate to get accurate locating. At that point, why not eliminate the middleman(bot)? Also, what is your accuracy requirement? Even $10k Lidar units have a bias error up to 30mm - would that be okay? How fast do you need this to work? Budget? Etc.